# How to test a callback of a mocked function with jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

A method of a third party service that I am using has a callback as the second argument. This callback is executed in real life when the response is received from the server.

I want to mock the third party method for unit testing, and supply different response arguments to the callback to ensure that its logic executes correctly. For example to check that the promise is rejected when the status is NOT 'success', or that on success just the saved record is returned and not the whole response.

I am using jasmine for testing.

```
function save() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  thirdPartyService.doSave(record, function callback(response) {
    // How to test the code in here when doSave is mocked?
    if(response.status === 'success') {
      deferred.resolve(response.savedRecord);
    } else {
      deferred.reject(response);
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Example of a test I'd like to run:

```
// Setup
const successResponse = {
  status: 'success',
  savedRecord: { Id: 'test-id' }
};
// Somehow config the mocked thirdParty.doSave() to use successResponse for the callback.

// Test
myService.save()
  .then(function(response) {
    expect(response.Id).toBe('test-id');
  });;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could mock `thirdParty.doSave` using `spyOn.and.callFake`.

```
const successResponse = {
  status: 'success',
  savedRecord: { Id: 'test-id' }
};
spyOn(thirdParty, 'doSave').and.callFake((record, callback) => callback(successResponse));
```